# Corenlp document level multithreading

Tags: multithreading, nlp, stanford-nlp, multicore, wikipedia

I have 8 million wikipedia articles to parse. I want to run 7 operations: tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref. Each document is taking approx 20 secs. In this rate it will take months to parse the whole data set in single thread. There is a 'nthreads' option for simultaneously parsing successive sentences. But co-reference analyzer cannot work on single sentence level. I can split my documents in multiple buckets and run corenlp on each of them simultaneously but that is resource hungry. Is there any simpler way to run multi-threaded corenlp at document level (not sentence) ? (I have  100 GB ram and 50 cores).

Comment: Not answering your question: You should use the shift-reduce parser if you aren't already. It is much faster at inference and is as or more accurate.

Comment: Have you thought about splitting the work across multiple machines using something like Hadoop?
Renting a hadoop cluster on amazon might work out to be much faster, cheaper, and easier than wrangling performance things on a single box

Comment: Yes, I am going to use Hadoop.

Comment: Can you just create different pipeline objects in multiple threads? Use `Executor`s with documents being the level of granularity?

Comment: I tried shift-reduce parser and it is much faster compared to the default dp based parser. Thanks @JonGauthier. :)